# why in my rendered image there are little white dots?

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine

Hi guys im just wondering why my viewport and rendered image are not same if you can see in my rendered image there little white dots and cand do same as viewport can someone show me some way to fix this[image]

Comment: there was a similar questions few days ago and I wonder if it's not a denoising setting problem

Comment: But i didnt use denoising

Comment: Any solution of this problem guys